# Android native c++ program sleep too long when there are lots of vector operation

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

As the topic, I wrote a cpp file and built it with ndk:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <vector>

struct timeval start;
struct timeval finish;
unsigned long spend;
std::vector<char> test_v1;
std::vector<char> test_v2;

void* test(void* data) {
    
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 512; i++)
    {
        test_v2.push_back(1);
    }

    printf("START\n");

    while(1){
        
        for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                test_v1.insert(test_v1.end(), test_v2.begin(), test_v2.end());
            }
            
            for(int i = 0; i < test_v1.size(); i++)
            {
                test_v1.at(i) = 0;
            }
            
            test_v1.clear();
        }
        
        //pthread_mutex_lock(&_p_mutex);
        gettimeofday(&start, NULL);
        usleep(16000);
        gettimeofday(&finish, NULL);

        spend = 1000000 * (finish.tv_sec-start.tv_sec)+ finish.tv_usec-start.tv_usec;
        if(spend > 30000){
            printf("[ERROR] : over 30ms, spend = %lu\n", spend);
        }

        count++;

        if(count >= 180){
            printf("Keep Alive, spend %lu\n", spend);
            count = 0;
        }
        
        for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                test_v1.insert(test_v1.end(), test_v2.begin(), test_v2.end());
            }
            
            for(int i = 0; i < test_v1.size(); i++)
            {
                test_v1.at(i) = 0;
            }
            
            test_v1.clear();
        }
    }
    
    return 0;
}

int main(void){
    printf("No thread Test\n");
    int rtn = 0;
    
    test(NULL);

    return rtn;
}
```

The execution result:
[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXwrZ.png)

There were no other apps executing, and system loading was very light.

The most curious thing is this situation may not happen in different power on -> test -> power off cycle , and when a cycle it happens , it will always happens no matter how much times I restart the test, if I don't power off the android device.

Why the sleep time influenced by lots of vector operation?

System Spec

Android Version: 7.0

Device Root: Yes

Android NDK Version: r11c

Use Cygwin and ADB shell to execute.

Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := threadtest
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := threadtest.cpp

include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

Application.mk:

```
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := 4.9
APP_OPTIM := debug
APP_STL := gnustl_shared
APP_CPPFLAGS := -std=gnu++14 -frtti -fexceptions
APP_CFLAGS := -fopenmp -ggdb
APP_LDFLAGS := -llog -fopenmp 
APP_BUILD_SCRIPT := Android.mk
APP_PIE := true
```

EDIT:

I replaced vector operation with direct memory allocate and set.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <vector>

struct timeval start;
struct timeval finish;
unsigned long spend;

void* test(void* data) {
    
    int count = 0;
    printf("START\n");

    while(1){   
        
        for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            char* p = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 1000);
            
            for(int i = 0; i < (sizeof(char) * 1000); i++)
            {
                p[i] = 2;
            }
            
            for(int i = 0; i < (sizeof(char) * 1000); i++)
            {
                p[i] = 1;
            }
            
            for(int i = 0; i < (sizeof(char) * 1000); i++)
            {
                p[i] = 0;
            }
            
            free(p);
        }

        gettimeofday(&start, NULL);
        usleep(16000);
        gettimeofday(&finish, NULL);

        spend = 1000000 * (finish.tv_sec-start.tv_sec)+ finish.tv_usec-start.tv_usec;
        if(spend > 30000){
            printf("[ERROR] : over 30ms, spend = %lu\n", spend);
        }

        count++;

        if(count >= 180){
            printf("keep alive, spend %lu\n", spend);
            count = 0;
        }
        
        for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            char* p = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 1000);
            
            for(int i = 0; i < (sizeof(char) * 1000); i++)
            {
                p[i] = 2;
            }
            
            for(int i = 0; i < (sizeof(char) * 1000); i++)
            {
                p[i] = 1;
            }
            
            for(int i = 0; i < (sizeof(char) * 1000); i++)
            {
                p[i] = 0;
            }
            
            free(p);
        }
    }
    
    return 0;
}

int main(void){
    printf("No thread Test\n");
    int rtn = 0;
    
    test(NULL);

    return rtn;
}
```

The result is the same.

It seems lots of memory operation will cause this problem, but why? All of them should be finished before the first gettimeofday?

Comment: You talk about android but you show results from a windows machine. Did you perform the same experiment on an android device?

Comment: I use cygwin to execute adb shell, and execute that native program in adb shell.

Comment: Note that the documentation does not guarantee that usleep sleeps for exactly the amount of time you specify. That would allow the Android OS to wake up your process in lockstep with other processes to save power.

Comment: I know the real sleep time changes due to other processes's influence, but in this case there are no other heavy loading processes. The huge amount of memory operations only be done in the same thread, and they should finished before timer records. So I don't realize why it sleep 2-6 times more than I assigned, 20-30 millisecond will be more reasonable.

Comment: You're at the mercy or the OS' scheduler. For example, did you take a [wake lock](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock#cpu) before running your experiment? Did you rerun your test in an actual app, which has different scheduling priorities?

Answer (score 0):

The delay is not due to use of  vector, but because your code is not optimized. There is a time overhead for traversing of a vector. In your code, you're traversing the vector too frequently by calling inside the nested loop. push_back operations will perform faster than insert operations. For frequent insertions, a list will perform better.

Comment: These frequent vector operations are intended. In another project I found this problem, so I wrote this sample to test the influence of vector. I know the time overhead of these operations, but why they affect usleep? All the memory copy and set operation should finished before the first gettimeofday call.